# How to get filename from version history

Tags: version-history

I am trying to get all different file name from version history. Looks like sharepoint is not storing old filename.

I changed the filename multiple time and when I looked at version history I see all versions but could not get the file name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes here 7 years later looking for the answer, it took me some time to find but in the folder list, open the contextual menu (with a right click on the file, or with the three stacked dots) and select "Details" at the bottom of the menu. At the bottom there is a section "more details" that give you info about the renamings.

[image: open contextual menu from the file]
[image: look for the "more details" section]

Answer (score 1):

If it is a word/ excel/ ppt or pdf file then you can click on any version and it would popout a window asking you to open the file/document and it will also show the name of the file and also all the names given by you to that particular document as shown in the image below.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Not giving me the old file name

Answer (score 1):

The file name is not included in the version history.

If you restore an older version the content of the document and the fields will be restored but not the old file name.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to get this.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Unfortunately there is no way